# MS Access, automated updating query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query which shows many other columns even though they are the same thing,

For example if I have my column names : "Breast Imaging" and "BREAST IMAGING" with the numbers of "6" and "8"

although they are the same things they are differentiated by two other columns with two other numbers, how can I sum up those columns automatically? do I have to use updating query?

For example : if I have a query like

Name / Total number of scans / Breast Imaging / BREAST IMAGING / CT / MRI

Arvin /         16          /       6        /       8        /  1  /  1

How can I make it like

Name / Total number of scans / Breast Imaging / CT / MRI

Arvin /         16          /       14          / 1  /  1

I made the tables with the crosstab query wizard

Comment: what do you mean by 'sum up those columns?' and could you specify what is the numbers you are talking about? any example?

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data.

Comment: Welcomo to SO. Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` tag for MS Access questions. They're completely different databases.

Comment: If you want an accurate answer, please add the SQL for your crosstab query to your question.  Otherwise, everyone is just going to take stabs in the dark at what's really going on in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 SELECT [Name], 
        [Total number of scans], 
        [Breast Imaging], 
        [BREAST IMAGING], 
        [CT], 
        [MRI]
```

Use:

```
 SELECT [Name], 
        [Total number of scans], 
        [Breast Imaging] + [BREAST IMAGING] as [Breast Imaging],  
        [CT], 
        [MRI]
```

Comment: Thank you but where do I put above code? I made my table by crosstab query and I can't find where the "SELECT" is

Comment: You really need to read How to Ask ... You can't make a question about crosstab and dont mention you have a cross tab :'(

Comment: sorry about that.. the tables above are based on the cross tab I will fix it now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the data type for those Breast Imaging / BREAST IMAGING columns?

IF they are `int`, you could do this:

```
     SELECT Name,
            [Total number of scans],
            [Breast Imaging] + [BREAST IMAGING] as New,
            CT,
            MRI 
        FROM TABLE
```

If they are not int type, use

```
     SELECT Name,
            [Total number of scans],
            cast([Breast Imaging] as int) + cast([BREAST IMAGING] as int) as New,
            CT,
            MRI 
        FROM TABLE
```